# convert svg into base64 for helmet pattern

Tags: javascript, svg

I have written simple svg :

```
 function Dot() {
  return (
    <svg width="12" height="12">
      <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="5.5" fill={headerColor} />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

I need to encode this in base64 for displaying in pageTitle. Is there some way how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `XMLSerializer` to convert your SVG to a string, and then use `btoa` to convert the string to base64:

```
var str = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById("svg"));
var encodedSVG = window.btoa(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the function should return a string. Then you can use `btoa` to convert it into base64

```js
function Dot() {
  return '<svg width="12" height="12"><circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="5.5" fill={headerColor} />'
}
var encodedString = btoa(Dot());
console.log(encodedString);
```

Comment: you were of course right, i forgot to return it as a string, but when i use this i see in header directly base64 code and this is a dot.

Comment: this is my code:                                                                                           const dot = btoa(`<svg width="12" height="12"><circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="5.5" fill={${headerColor}}/></svg>`);
    return (
      <Dialog>
        <Helmet
          title={`${dot} Incoming call`}
          meta={[
            { name: 'Incoming call modal', content: 'Incoming Call modal' },
          ]}
        />